# How to create Javascript/Jquery events dynamically?

Tags: javascript, jquery, foreach, hover

I have 4 bootstrap cards their ids are:
card0
card1
card2
card3
and I have 4 label marks their ids are:
mark0
mark1
mark2
mark3

I want to add 4 different events in each Card:

```
for (var i = 0; i < 4; i++) {
  var cardx = '#card' + i;
  var markx = '#mark' + i;

  $(cardx).hover(function (i) {
    $(markx).removeClass('map-icon map-icon-beauty-salon');
    $(markx).addClass('map-icon map-icon-postal-code-prefix');
  }, function (i) {
    $(markx).removeClass('map-icon map-icon-postal-code-prefix');
    $(markx).addClass('map-icon map-icon-beauty-salon');
  });
}
```

The code above only create the same event in the 4 cards

Comment: can you plz post your html and css code?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to use `each` loop in stand of `for`

Try this:

```js
$(document).ready(function(){
    
    $('.cardHolder div').each(function (i) {
        var markx = '#mark' + i;
        $(this).hover(function() {
            $(markx).removeClass('map-icon map-icon-beauty-salon');
            $(markx).addClass('map-icon map-icon-postal-code-prefix');
        }, function () {
            $(markx).removeClass('map-icon map-icon-postal-code-prefix');
            $(markx).addClass('map-icon map-icon-beauty-salon');
        });
    })

});
```

```css
label{display:block}
.map-icon-beauty-salon{
    color:#0094ff;
}
.map-icon-postal-code-prefix{
    color:#ff6a00;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<p>Hover mouse on Card : </p>
<div class="cardHolder">
    <div id="card0">Card 1</div>
    <div id="card1">Card 2</div>
    <div id="card2">Card 3</div>
    <div id="card3">Card 4</div>
</div>
<hr />

<label id="mark0">Mark 1</label>
<label id="mark1">Mark 2</label>
<label id="mark2">Mark 3</label>
<label id="mark3">Mark 4</label>
```

Comment: This works for me. I made a little change $("div[id^='card']").each(function)

Answer (score 0):

It will add hover events to each of #card[i] element.
The problem is #mark[i] elements.
Because of closure issue, it will always act on #mark3.
You should attach i to the event and use that value.

```
$(cards).on('mouseenter', {i: i}, function (e) {
  var markx = '#mark' + e.data.i;
  $(markx).removeClass('map-icon map-icon-beauty-salon');
  $(markx).addClass('map-icon map-icon-postal-code-prefix');
}).on('mouseleave', {i: i}, function (e) {
  var markx = '#mark' + e.data.i;
  $(markx).removeClass('map-icon map-icon-postal-code-prefix');
  $(markx).addClass('map-icon map-icon-beauty-salon');
});
```